# Passing data between different classes swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I have a classes A, B, C, D(B, C, D are view controllers). class A has a timer and on timer elapsed I want that my controllers receive the data from A and update accordingly.

Below is my class A

```
class MembersStatusUpdateManager{

var timer:NSTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 60*5, target: "self", selector: "updateStatuses", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
var deltaToken:String = ""
var statusData:NSMutableArray? = nil
var deleteage:MembersStatuUpdatedDelegate?

func startTimer(){
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func updateStatuses(){
    //Update the statues
}
```

}

I know using protocol/delegate I can send data to the classes but in that case I have create 3 delegates, one for each class, is there any other better solution for this?

Comment: Yes, NSNotificationCenter

Comment: To Use NSNotificaiton, you need to ensure that view controllers B,C & D need to be instantiated. For eg : If you have a view controller hierarchy such that B -> C -> D . and right now only B is on screen. C & D are not yet created so they wont get the notification.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to right direction NSNoficationCenter is the best suited solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global class concept, Here is the solution for this.

First create a global class

```
import Foundation


 class User {
  class var sharedInstance: User {
  struct Static {
       static var instance: User?
       static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
  }

 dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
    Static.instance = User()
 }

 return Static.instance!

 }

var timer: NSTimer?
```

}

then store data in the class that you want

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController { 

let user = User.sharedInstance


 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        self.user.timer = thisTime
   } 
 }
}
```

Then retrieve data :-

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    let user = User.sharedInstance
    mylabel.text = self.user.timer
```

}